# Cross domain requests: Javascript vs Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, security, browser

As you might know, browser's security model does not allow a script loaded in a page from http://www.example.com to make cross-domain requests (no AJAX calls to any other domain other than www.example.com). The Javascript file itself could have been served from a different domain altogether (www.javascript.com/myscript.js) and that is irrelevant. This is the Same-Origin Policy.

Flash also has something similar? But does Flash treat the origin to be the HTML page where the .swf file was **loaded** or origin is the domain which **served** the .swf file?

So http://www.example.com loads a .swf file from http://www.swf.com/myflash.swf. Now .swf can load resources only from www.example.com or only www.swf.com? I'm assuming there are no cross-domain.xml files setup on either example.com or swf.com.

Comment: This is a good question, interested in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, this article explains a lot about the problem you mention: http://www.foregroundsecurity.com/MyBlog/flash-origin-policy-issues.html

From there:

> For website owners, all user-supplied
>   content should be served from a
>   completely separate domain. This is
>   already implemented by Yahoo mail,
>   Hotmail, Wikipedia, and many other
>   major websites, but a huge variety of
>   self-contained web applications do not
>   do so (and if I can, for example,
>   upload a malicious file to
>   "apiwiki.twiitter.com", I can perform
>   cross-subdomain cookie attacks). A
>   partial solution was made possible by
>   Flash 10,0,0,2: SWF files served with
>   a "content-Disposition: attachment"
>   header will not execute when embedded
>   in a web page. If all user-generated
>   content is served with this header
>   (not a bad idea in any case), it may
>   limit your exposure, but this is not a
>   very robust solution.

It sounds like if you serve the content from a different domain and there are no cross-domain policy files, then flash cannot access files from your main server.

Also, this article: http://supergeekery.com/index.php/geekblog/2009/12 states that

> And everything I write should be able
>   to trust each other and share with
>   each other. You may wonder if Flash
>   Ads are a problem. Do they have this
>   problem? No, there are Flash ads all
>   over the internet, but since they are
>   almost never hosted on the same server
>   as the domain you’re visiting, **they
>   don’t get to access the data the web
>   site’s primary code’s data**. Cool.

Comment: The Flash Ads argument does make sense. The Flash ad's swf should be able to load content from the adserver but unable to access anything from the server which has the ad embedded in a page.

This should also explain how sites like youtube, scribd.com can support embedding on 3rd-party sites. When they provide you with the <embed> code they don't really know where you're going to embed that  object (which means they cannot really go and edit their cross-domain.xml to include your domain).